# How to get my system to use node version installed by Homebrew?

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

On OS X, when I run `node --version` I get `v12.9.1`. I ran `brew upgrade node` and it warned me `Warning: node 15.3.0 already installed`. I ran `brew uninstall node`, but then when I ran `node --version` I still got `v12.9.1`.

**What I Want To Know: **
Why does my system say that my node version is 12.9.1 when 15.30.0 is installed? How can I get it so that my system is using 15.3.0 instead of 12.9.1?

Comment: have you tried running `brew link --overwrite node`

Comment: Then, make sure you open a new terminal tab and run `node --version`